React Hook Form with shadcn: How to select multi checkbox
I'm using React Hook Form with shadcn UI components and zod for validation in my React project. I have a list of services where each checkbox represents a service, and I want to store the selected service IDs in an array field (serviceDetails.services). When a checkbox is checked, I want to add the service ID to the array; when unchecked, I want to remove it.
Here is my current code using shadcn's Checkbox component:
//constants.ts
const SERVICES = ["fitness", "sauna", "cardio"] as const;

//schema.ts
const serviceDetailsSchema = z.object({
  services: z.array(z.enum(SERVICES)),
  totalAmount: z.number().min(0, "Total amount must be non-negative"),
});
export const memberEntrySchema = z.object({
  serviceDetails: serviceDetailsSchema,
});

//types.ts
export type MemberEntryFormData = z.infer<typeof memberEntrySchema>;


//MemberEntryForm.tsx

const MemberEntryForm = () => {
  const services = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Fitness",
      price: 1000,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Sauna",
      price: 500,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Cardio",
      price: 800,
    },
  ];

const methods = useForm<MemberEntryFormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(memberEntrySchema),
    defaultValues: {
      //other forms default values aswell
      serviceDetails: {
        services: [],
        totalAmount: 0,
      },
    },
  });
 const onSubmit = (data: MemberEntryFormData) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
 return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-6">
    //other forms aswell
    <ServiceDetailsForm services={services} />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
)


//ServiceDetailsForm.tsx

type ServiceDetailsFormProps = {
  services: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
  }[];
};

const ServiceDetailsForm = ({ services }: ServiceDetailsFormProps) => {
  const { control, watch } = useFormContext<MemberEntryFormData>();
  const servicesValue = watch("serviceDetails.services");

  console.log(servicesValue);

  const items = services.map((service) => ({
    id: service.name + " - " + service.price + "/month",
    label: service.name + " - " + service.price + "/month",
  }));
  return (
    <div className="space-y-2">
      <Heading3>Service Details</Heading3>
      <FormField
        control={control}
        name="serviceDetails.services"
        render={() => (
          <FormItem>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <FormLabel className="text-base">Sidebar</FormLabel>
            </div>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <FormField
                key={item.id}
                control={control}
                name={`serviceDetails.services`}
                render={({ field }) => {
                  return (
                    <FormItem
                      key={item.id}
                      className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0"
                    >
                      <FormControl>
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={field.value?.includes(item.id)}
                          onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                            const updatedValues = Array.isArray(field.value)
                              ? field.value
                              : [];
                            if (checked) {
                              field.onChange([...updatedValues, item.id]);
                            } else {
                              field.onChange(
                                updatedValues.filter(
                                  (value) => value !== item.id
                                )
                              );
                            }
                          }}
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormLabel className="font-normal">
                        {item.label}
                      </FormLabel>
                    </FormItem>
                  );
                }}
              />
            ))}
            <FormMessage />
          </FormItem>
        )}
      />
      //other form fields
   </div>
  );
};
    

I'm encountering an "undefined" error when submitting the form. Here's the error.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Can you please provide a more complete example of your code? I wasn't able to reproduce the error

I have updated @jasperan, let me know if you required anything else

@Jasperan, are you able to reproduct this issue?

I was able to get rid of the undefined error. The first thing I did was simplifying the id for the items variable so it matches your SERVICES constant.
const items = services.map((service) => ({
      id: service.name.toLowerCase() as typeof SERVICES[number], // Change this line
      label: service.name + " - " + service.price + "/month",
}));

Then in your Checkbox component, I changed the checked attribute to this, so it matches the item's id correctly:
<Checkbox
    checked={servicesValue?.includes(item.id as typeof SERVICES[number])}

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it does get rid of the undefined error for me.

Yeah, for me too it's working when converted the id to lowercase.  Thanks @Jasperan
